# Gradle doesn't use new environment variables on task rerun

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle task that runs a commandline script. Previously, I would run multiple tasks using different environment variables. For example:

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=nonprod INITIAL_SYNC_DATABASE=my_db INITIAL_SYNC_MODE=create ./gradlew -p connectmanager run`

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=nonprod INITIAL_SYNC_DATABASE=my_other_db INITIAL_SYNC_MODE=create ./gradlew -p connectmanager run`

This would spawn two different jobs on a remote server with different values in `INITIAL_SYNC_DATABASE`.

However, I recently tried doing this and no matter what value I put in `INITIAL_SYNC_DATABASE`, the task would always use whatever I input the first time I ran the task. The only way I have found to get around this is to run `./gradlew --stop` after every invocation, and then set my new variables. Is this expected behavior? I don't recall this being an issue in the past, but I've recently upgraded to a new machine, so I'm wondering if it's related to that? I'm on an Apple M1 chip and running Java 11 (Zulu)

Comment: It could have to do with reusing Gradle daemons of a previous run (and thus with the old environment variables). Try running with `--no-daemon` or `org.gradle.daemon=false` in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: To confirm - do re-used gradle daemons not pick up new env vars? I'll give the `--no-daemon` option a try, that sounds helpful

Comment: I don't know, I'm just guessing for you to have an avenue of exploration, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer. AFAIK, environment variables of a process are fixed after it's started (though that might be a wrong assumption on my part).